# Print the path using grep (or alternative commands)

Tags: bash, grep

In bash file I have:
`Path="/home/name/logs/*.log"`, and I need to print just `/home/name/logs`.
How can I use `grep` (or other commands) to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you certainly *could* use `grep` to this<sup>1</sup>, I'd recommend using the shell's own [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) features instead

```
$ Path="/home/name/logs/*.log"
$ echo "${Path%/*}"
/home/name/logs
```

or the `dirname` command

```
$ dirname "$Path"
/home/name/logs
```

---

<sup>1</sup> for example `grep -Po '.*(?=/)' <<<"$Path"` or (if you don't mind the trailing slash) `grep -o '.*/' <<<"$Path"`

Comment: tried just now, thank you!